# When I use python-docx merge word-documents,the output file is damaged

Tags: python, ms-office

I use python-docx merge docx,the code is:

```py
from docx import Document

local_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
source_path = local_path + "/source/"
normal_path = source_path + "normal/"
output_file = Document()

files = os.listdir(normal_path)
files.sort()

for filename in files:
    print(filename)
    sub_doc = Document(normal_path + filename)
    for element in sub_doc.element.body:
        output_file.element.body.append(element)

output_file.save("output.docx")
```

the output file can not open in office-word,it was damaged.

And when I use office fix tool fix output file, the output file can not show the image.(I insert image in input file).

So how to correctly output file, and image are not damaged？

Thanks Help.

Comment: This is not your complete code, so it's hard to tell what could go wrong. Please [edit] your question to post a [mcve], so that it's easier for us to help you. Also, it looks like you're using `element` to mean two different things; as a first debugging measure, please rename the for loop `element` to something else.

Comment: This is all my "merge" code.I have some .docx file in folder, it can help me merge them. Just, the output file is damaged.

Comment: Are your pictures inline? Because the `python-docx` documentation [explicitly says](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/shapes.html#understanding-pictures-and-other-shapes) that floating images/shapes are not currently (version 0.8.9) supported.

Comment: I fix the problem. the template word-document have watermark. I merge it cause damage the file.And python-docx can not merge image, so I need find another plan.

Comment: Actually, I tried merging two simple docx files (just text, no images), and I got the Word "fix document" message too. Anyway, is there any chance you could switch to using Word itself for this? For example, [this article](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/969-word-merge-multiple-documents.html) gives both a `Text from File` method and a VBA method. (The VBA method is basically just a fancy copy-paste from each document into the currently opened document, so you can test it yourself manually first. If that works, I can adapt it to automatically use your template file.)